# What is suitable way to avoid shared locks and exclusive locks?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, postgresql-9.1

I have sufficiently highload system built with `PostgreSql 9.1` and `PHP 5.3`.

I have to store last login time and ip user each time after user login. When user logins system stores it to `Redis` and I have script in crontab which executes each minute and fetches data from `Redis` and updates user's rows with last login time and ip in DB with one big query.

If at this moment some scripts starts to execute update query of user table I could find shared locks errors in `PostgreSql` log. Huge problem that php scripts fall down when this error happens in `PostgreSql` without any exception from PDO.

I know to avoid shared locks I need to execute update query one after the other, not concurrently. But to implement it isn't so easy in my system.
What is the best approach to avoid shared locks?